# Cell-dependent cell ranges in data validation in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Regarding Google Sheets -- is there any way to have cell-ranges in data validation depend on the cell itself. For instance, I want G7 to accept input only from E7 and F7. Similarly, I want G8 to accept input only from E8 and F8. But if I copy and paste the data validation from G7 to G8, G8 will incorrectly accept input from E7 and F7 rather than E8 and F8. Sure, I can just do G8 manually, but if I want to be able to do this a thousand times, it's not exactly feasible!

One potential solution that occurred to me would be to include the ROW function in the data validation, but I think I would need to use a custom formula for that and I can't come up with a custom formula that outputs a range. I'd appreciate any advice!

BTW - the motivation for this is to create a Google Sheet implementation of a March Madness bracket where the prices (or payoffs) are endogenous, i.e. determined by people's selections. The Google sheet has a lot of neat features to do it, particularly because everybody can access it online and I can give people editing privileges to just their row of entries. I'll link the bracket here if/when I ever get it up and running!

UPDATE - it turns out you can do this easily in Excel as you can use the $ sign in the data validation just as you can in a formula so that when you copy and paste it updates anything that isn't fixed by $. Google Sheets ignores a $ sign if you put it into the data validation range because and just fixes it either way.

Comment: You might write a script to automate the validation rule creation https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation

Comment: @ZigMandel So I would create it under Tools/Script Editor? I'm not familiar with JavaScript, but could probably stumble my way into a solution. My main problem though is that I would need my function to output a range of cells (rather than a value), and I'd also like the sheet to recognize it as a range and give a drop down list to select from that range. Is that seem possible, or am I on a fool's errand?

Comment: It would be great if I could just specify a range as A'ROW()':B'ROW()'. There's no magical syntax to call functions like that inside a range, is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **Custom formula is** as a validation rule of:

```
 =or(G1=offset(G1,0,-2),G1=offset(G1,0,-1))
```

applied to the whole of ColumnG should work on the 'row by row' basis I think you require.

[OR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093306)
[OFFSET](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379)